# JAXB/MOXy use same Entity-type for several properties

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have a rather large object tree which I want to export to XML. An object named Person is used at several places (as userCreated, userModified of many child entities, as client, etc)

Depending of the use of the Person-object I need to have different elements in the xml. Example:

```
<policy>
  <userCreated>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  </userCreated>
  <client>
    <clientId>1234</clientId>
    <email>jdoe@example.com</email>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  </client>
</policy>
```

userCreated and client are instances of the same object (named Person)

How can this be set up in bindings.xml ?

Comment: The `Person` class has properties `clientId`, `email`, ` firstName`, `lastName` and based on where the object appears you want to restrict which properties are marshalled to XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` extension to support this use case.  What `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` allows you to do is create multiple views on your data.

**Person**

Below we will use `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` to create a view on the `Person` class that only exposes 2 fields (`firstName` and `lastName`).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlNamedObjectGraph(
    name = "simple", 
    attributeNodes = {
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("firstName"), 
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("lastName")
     }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    private int clientId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public void setClientId(int clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**Policy**

We will also use `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` on the `Policy` class.  It says that for the `userCreated` field apply the named object graph called `simple` that we defined on the `Person` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlNamedObjectGraph(
    name = "policy", 
    attributeNodes = {
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode(value = "userCreated", subgraph = "simple"),
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("client") 
    }
)
public class Policy {

    private Person userCreated;
    private Person client;

    public void setUserCreated(Person userCreated) {
        this.userCreated = userCreated;
    }

    public void setClient(Person client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will specify the named object graph that we want applied on the `Marshaller` using the `MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH` property.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Policy.class);

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setClientId(1234);
        person.setFirstName("John");
        person.setLastName("Doe");
        person.setEmail("jdoe@example.com");

        Policy policy = new Policy();
        policy.setClient(person);
        policy.setUserCreated(person);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "policy");
        marshaller.marshal(policy, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<policy>
   <userCreated>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
   </userCreated>
   <client>
      <clientId>1234</clientId>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <email>jdoe@example.com</email>
   </client>
</policy>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and helpful post! Since I use an external binding document, I wonder if I can set up several xml-named-object-graph for my Person object, and "refer" to those from inside the <java-type name="Policy" xml-accessor-type="NONE">  (or better from inside <xml-element java-attribute="userCreated" />) ? I would like to avoid annotations and work with external binding documents solely. Also, I would like to configure as much as possible in the external binding document, and the least possible from Java.

Comment: @yglodt - The following link has an example of configuring the named object graph in the external mapping document:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html